# Copy queue items into another class object

Tags: c++, queue

When I will display the items in a queue I use the while loop

```
while (!queue.isEmptyQueue())
{
    cout << queue.front() << " ";
    queue.deleteQueue();
}
```

The items will be gone because of the `deleteQueue()` function so I cannot display it again.
How can I create a copy of the queue?

I tried the code below but it gives me errors.

```
queue1 = queue;
while (!queue1.isEmptyQueue())
{
    cout << queue1.front() << " ";
    queue1.deleteQueue();
}
```

I am using `linkedQueue.h`

```
#include<assert.h>

template <class Type>
struct nodeType
{
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};

template <class Type>
class linkedQueueType  //: public queueADT<Type>
{
    public:
        const linkedQueueType<Type>& operator=(const         linkedQueueType<Type>&);
        bool isEmptyQueue() const;
        bool isFullQueue() const;
        void initializeQueue();
        Type front() const;
        Type back() const;
        void addQueue(const Type& queueElement);
        void deleteQueue();
        linkedQueueType();
        linkedQueueType(const linkedQueueType<Type>& otherQueue);
        ~linkedQueueType();
    private:
        nodeType<Type> *queueFront; 
        nodeType<Type> *queueRear; 
};

template <class Type>
bool linkedQueueType<Type>::isEmptyQueue() const
{
    return(queueFront == NULL);
}

template <class Type>
bool linkedQueueType<Type>::isFullQueue() const
{
    return false;
} 

template <class Type>
void linkedQueueType<Type>::initializeQueue()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;
    while (queueFront!= NULL) 
    {
        temp = queueFront; 
        queueFront = queueFront->link; 
        delete temp; 
    }
    queueRear = NULL; 
} 

template <class Type>
void linkedQueueType<Type>::addQueue(const Type& newElement)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;
    newNode = new nodeType<Type>; 
    newNode->info = newElement; 
    newNode->link = NULL; 
    if (queueFront == NULL) 
    {
        queueFront = newNode;
        queueRear = newNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        queueRear->link = newNode;
        queueRear = queueRear->link;
    }
}

template <class Type>
Type linkedQueueType<Type>::front() const
{
    assert(queueFront != NULL);
    return queueFront->info;
} 
template <class Type>
Type linkedQueueType<Type>::back() const
{
    assert(queueRear!= NULL);
    return queueRear->info;
} 

template <class Type>
void linkedQueueType<Type>::deleteQueue()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;
    if (!isEmptyQueue())
    {
    temp = queueFront; 
    queueFront = queueFront->link; 
    delete temp; 
    if (queueFront == NULL) 
    queueRear = NULL; 
    }
    else
    cout << "Cannot remove from an empty queue" << endl;
}

template<class Type>
linkedQueueType<Type>::linkedQueueType()
{
    queueFront = NULL; 
    queueRear = NULL; 
} 

template <class Type>
linkedQueueType<Type>::~linkedQueueType()
{
    initializeQueue();
}
```

Comment: You have omitted the definition of the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is copy the queue, then a copy constructor / assignment operator is what you should have, as Martin said.

But if what you want is for the items to still be there after you go through the queue, then what your queue is missing is a way to tell how many items are in the queue.

You can cout each item and then move it to the back of the queue, that number of times.

Either way, all of these are missing for it to be a good queue implementation.
Copy constructor, assignment operator, size function.

(And technically, a queue doesn't have functionality to access the back item. So I wouldn't call this a queue with missing functionality, I would call it a linked list with missing functionality.)

Comment: I suggest a *good* queue implementation also needs a move constructor and a move assignment operator.  Possibly also a way to iterate through the queue elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `linkedQueueType` doesn't have an assignment operator so the compiler is giving you one which just copies the pointers.  You need an assignment operator which clones the elements.